# I've followed official guides to SDL on Android but its not making libmain.so

Tags: android, eclipse, sdl

`SDLActivity` calls `loadLibrary("main")` but it's just `libSDL2.so` there. I struggled getting this far and have almost no experience of `Android.mk`, despite having built native android applications with cocos2d-x. Is it `Android.mk` I must investigate to create this library? I've got DinoMage's `jni/src/main.c` in place and have a stub extending `SDLActivity` under my package name.

Sorry for no code, there's lots, everywhere, only it's location and `Android.mk` could differ from DinoMage's guide, which approximates to the supplied readme for android anyway.

I'm using Eclipse for Windows 7x64

Here's the relevant logcat:

```
10-05 01:11:14.623: W/dalvikvm(3903): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/libsdl/app/SDLActivity;
10-05 01:11:14.623: W/dalvikvm(3903): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lmydomain/myproject/myactivity;)
10-05 01:11:56.760: D/AndroidRuntime(3903): Shutting down VM
10-05 01:11:56.761: W/dalvikvm(3903): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414bd908)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5022)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1032)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load main: findLibrary returned null
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     at org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity.<clinit>(SDLActivity.java:54)
10-05 01:11:56.783: E/AndroidRuntime(3903):     ... 15 more
```

I've tried this again using a different method of importing existing code (copied into workspace from extraction location) and set it up to get the same error, again. For a while I was missing libSDL2.so but I updated the manifest as the comments suggested and extended SDLActivity the missing libSDL2.so error was gone again. App went from 68k to 872k but this time the library is not visible within Eclipse. Now I still need libmain.so. and I haven't even bothered creating `main.c` this time, yet. Could this be the answer?

*edit*

Right track, I need main.c, or maybe not, but I got it anyway as the app doesn't appear to do anything otherwise.

Speaking of not doing anything Eclipse appears willing to run any old balls on my phone. I need to run ndk-build (as advised in the ndk documentation) and then I get, er, more errors, but at least they're compile time.

**One** important difference to DinoMage's advice comes with the wholesale copying over of the unzipped SDL to my new project. It will overwrite `Android.mk`. I've been playing around with different versions, the one which came with the project-android folder produces:

[armeabi] Compile thumb  : main <= main.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : main <= SDL_android_main.c
In file included from c:/Users/ME/workspace3/SDLActivity//jni/src/main/an
droid/SDL_android_main.c:4:0:
c:/Users/ME/workspace3/SDLActivity//jni/src/main/android/../../SDL_intern
al.h:34:24: fatal error: SDL_config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [c:/Users/ME/workspace3/SDLActivity//obj/local/armeabi/objs
/main/main/android/SDL_android_main.o] Error 1

Which seems to explicitly differentiate it's `main` target from the other much longer `Android.mk`, from the root of the SDL directory. The longer one appears to target the other library I need `SDL2`, and fails to build that to, although for the very same reason

[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_android_main.c
c:/Users/ME/workspace3/SDLActivity//jni/src/SDL_android_main.c:4:32: fata
l error: ../../SDL_internal.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [c:/Users/ME/workspace3/SDLActivity//obj/local/armeabi/objs
/SDL2/src/SDL_android_main.o] Error 1

I've been through these includes and corrected a couple but I don't want to get into too deeply modifying the supposedly *good* library code.

Out of habit and to get things working better, I edited Android.mk in the subfolder `jni/src` to

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  main.c \
                    main/android/SDL_android_main.c
```

from the template

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c \
                    $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c
```

The whole `jni/src/Android.mk` is now:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := main
SDL_PATH := ../SDL

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include

# Add your application source files here...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  main.c \
                    main/android/SDL_android_main.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I think my paths are messed up but there are too many different ways to import this code into Eclipse and I've only found too ways that work even this much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty hack would be changing

```
SDL_PATH := ../SDL
```

to

```
SDL_PATH := ../jni
```

since that is where we are told to paste it by, ["Then copy (or symlink) the whole SDL directory and put it into your project’s jni directory"](http://www.dinomage.com/2013/01/howto-sdl-on-android/)

This gets ndk-build chugging along for a while until failing to find EGL! which it never can, time for another question, or abandonment:

> ```
> Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: "C:\Users\ME\workspace3\SDLActivity\jni\src"
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_android_main.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_assert.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_error.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_hints.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_log.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= main.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_audio.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_audiocvt.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_audiodev.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_audiotypecvt.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_mixer.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_wave.c
> [armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_androidaudio.c
> In file included from c:/Users/ME/workspace3/SDLActivity//jni/src/audio/a
> ndroid/SDL_androidaudio.c:31:0:
> c:/Users/ME/workspace3/SDLActivity//jni/src/audio/android/../../core/andr
> oid/SDL_android.h:30:29: fatal error: EGL/eglplatform.h: No such file or directo
> ry
> compilation terminated.
> make.exe: *** [c:/Users/ME/workspace3/SDLActivity//obj/local/armeabi/objs
> /SDL2/src/audio/android/SDL_androidaudio.o] Error 1
> ```

The rest of the solution came from http://blog.csdn.net/jwzhangjie/article/details/9083827
ie creating `Application.mk` in jni directory to specify

`APP_PLATFORM := android-9`

This works but taking the advice of Ashoke would be optimal (re creating *jni/SDL* subfolder), if I'd just skipped to page 3 for DinoMage's tutorial where he states "*Put the SDL_ttf source directory alongside your **SDL** directory in your project (in jni/ so you get jni/**SDL_ttf***" I'd know that.

[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_test_md5.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_test_random.c
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libSDL2.so
[armeabi] Install        : libSDL2.so => libs/armeabi/libSDL2.so
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : main <= SDL_android_main.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : main <= main.c
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libmain.so
[armeabi] Install        : libmain.so => libs/armeabi/libmain.so

The demo from DinoMage now works.

Answer (score 0):

to create a shared library module named "main", in Android.mk you will need to declare

```
LOCAL_MODULE := main
```

this will result in "libmain.so" file.

please [see this example](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/704a0bfecf75/android-project/jni/src/Android_static.mk)

Comment: open a command prompt, and cd to folder that contains "jni" dir (do not `cd` into jni), run `ndk-build clean & ndk-build`, please update your question with output.

Comment: I don't know if `Android-static.mk` is being run by `ndk-build` by default? If I copy paste that one into `Android.mk` I get `Android NDK: pathToMk.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'SDL' in import path` .. `are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined. It isn't showing up in `set`, no one mentioned it so far... thanks

Comment: is your "android-project" [folder inside "SDL" parent folder](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/3331d2f57704) ?, if so , run the `ndk-build` command inside `SDL` folder

Comment: No, it's in the jni folder, as per DinoMage's instructions. Sorry for the delay the page refused to update properly and I'd just prepared a provisional answer, but couldn't submit. Please feel free to build on my answer, otherwise the question needs changing. Hmm there never was an `SDL` folder in the source it was called `SDL2-2.0.3` perhaps I should be copying _that_ folder to jni and renaming it to `SDL`?

Comment: yes, just copy folder SDL2-2.0.3 and rename as `SDL` into "jni" folder. And your [Android.mk needs to refer to SDL as static as shown in this android.mk](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/3331d2f57704/android-project/jni/src/Android_static.mk).

Comment: Thanks. Why does it "need to refer to SDL as static"? When I replace Android.mk with Android-static.mk libs/armeabi is empty and when I don't I get both the libraries I was looking for. Now I'm linking SDL__Image I can't find it and it's the only one that output "[armeabi] Install" instead of "[armeabi] SharedLibrary" on `ndk-build`. On `clean` there is an `SDL2_static` and `SDL2` but only an `SDL2_image`